# Prefect: User "system:serviceaccount:hm-prefect:prefect-worker" cannot create resource "jobs" in API group "batch" in the namespace "default"

Tags: kubernetes, prefect

As Prefect work pools and workers are now generally available after 2.11.0. I am trying to switch from Prefect Agent to Prefect Worker.

I deployed Prefect Server by

```bash
helm upgrade \
  prefect-server \
  prefect-server \
  --install \
  --repo=https://prefecthq.github.io/prefect-helm \
  --namespace=hm-prefect \
  --create-namespace \
  --values=prefect-server-values.yaml
```

**prefect-server-values.yaml**:

```yaml
server:
  image:
    repository: docker.io/prefecthq/prefect
    prefectTag: 2.11.0-python3.11-kubernetes
  publicApiUrl: https://prefect.mydomain.com/api
```

```bash
helm upgrade \
  prefect-worker \
  prefect-worker \
  --install \
  --repo=https://prefecthq.github.io/prefect-helm \
  --namespace=hm-prefect \
  --create-namespace \
  --values=prefect-worker-values.yaml
```

**prefect-worker-values.yaml**:

```yaml
worker:
  image:
    repository: docker.io/prefecthq/prefect
    prefectTag: 2.11.0-python3.11-kubernetes
  apiConfig: server
  config:
    workPool: hm-kubernetes-pool
  serverApiConfig:
    apiUrl: http://prefect-server.hm-prefect.svc:4200/api
```

```bash
➜ helm list -n hm-prefect
NAME            NAMESPACE   REVISION    UPDATED                                 STATUS      CHART                       APP VERSION
prefect-server  hm-prefect  1           2023-07-31 17:07:50.401888 -0700 PDT    deployed    prefect-server-2023.07.27   2.11.1
prefect-worker  hm-prefect  1           2023-07-31 17:18:57.586027 -0700 PDT    deployed    prefect-worker-2023.07.27   2.11.1

➜ kubectl get deployment -n hm-prefect
NAME             READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
prefect-server   1/1     1            1           17m
prefect-worker   1/1     1            1           6m2s
```

And I can see Prefect Worker in the UI:

[image]

Then I generated YAML file by:

```bash
➜ prefect deployment build src/main.py:print_platform --name=print-platform --infra-block=kubernetes-job/print-platform-kubernetes-job-block --apply --pool=hm-kubernetes-pool
Found flow 'print-platform'
Deployment YAML created at '/Users/hongbo-miao/Clouds/Git/hongbomiao.com/hm-prefect/workflows/print-platform/print_platform-deployment.yaml'.
Deployment storage None does not have upload capabilities; no files uploaded.  Pass --skip-upload to suppress this warning.
Deployment 'print-platform/print-platform' successfully created with id '7f7603ca-697c-4dca-9bcb-28a889165fe8'.
```

Here is the generated file **print_platform-deployment.yaml** content:

```yaml
###
### A complete description of a Prefect Deployment for flow 'print-platform'
###
name: print-platform
description: null
version: e4da5dae95465f73a0e3e0bece1555bb
# The work queue that will handle this deployment's runs
work_queue_name: default
work_pool_name: hm-kubernetes-pool
tags: []
parameters: {}
schedule: null
is_schedule_active: true
infra_overrides: {}

###
### DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
###
flow_name: print-platform
manifest_path: null
infrastructure:
  type: kubernetes-job
  env: {}
  labels: {}
  name: null
  command: null
  image: ghcr.io/hongbo-miao/hm-prefect-print-platform:latest
  namespace: hm-prefect
  service_account_name: null
  image_pull_policy: Always
  cluster_config: null
  job:
    apiVersion: batch/v1
    kind: Job
    metadata:
      labels: {}
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          parallelism: 1
          completions: 1
          restartPolicy: Never
          containers:
          - name: prefect-job
            env: []
  customizations: []
  job_watch_timeout_seconds: null
  pod_watch_timeout_seconds: 60
  stream_output: true
  finished_job_ttl: null
  _block_document_id: 1f5b585c-581d-4ca4-adfa-c69dc5319941
  _block_document_name: print-platform-kubernetes-job-block
  _is_anonymous: false
  block_type_slug: kubernetes-job
  _block_type_slug: kubernetes-job
storage: null
path: /opt/prefect/flows
entrypoint: src/main.py:print_platform
parameter_openapi_schema:
  title: Parameters
  type: object
  properties: {}
  required: null
  definitions: null
timestamp: '2023-08-01T00:32:45.975410+00:00'
triggers: []
```

Next, I try to run by

```bash
➜ prefect deployment run print-platform/print-platform
Creating flow run for deployment 'print-platform/print-platform'...
Created flow run 'onyx-fennec'.
└── UUID: 065326e7-1d3e-455a-86fb-b15d553af5bd
└── Parameters: {}
└── Scheduled start time: 2023-07-31 17:32:50 PDT (now)
└── URL: https://prefect.mydomain.com/flow-runs/flow-run/065326e7-1d3e-455a-86fb-b15d553af5bd
```

However, this gives me error:

```
Worker 'KubernetesWorker 180550e0-fe47-4a0d-998d-b772d53e14b0' submitting flow run '065326e7-1d3e-455a-86fb-b15d553af5bd'
Creating Kubernetes job...

Failed to submit flow run '065326e7-1d3e-455a-86fb-b15d553af5bd' to infrastructure.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/prefect_kubernetes/worker.py", line 628, in _create_job
    job = batch_client.create_namespaced_job(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api/batch_v1_api.py", line 210, in create_namespaced_job
    return self.create_namespaced_job_with_http_info(namespace, body, **kwargs)  # noqa: E501
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api/batch_v1_api.py", line 309, in create_namespaced_job_with_http_info
    return self.api_client.call_api(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 348, in call_api
    return self.__call_api(resource_path, method,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 180, in __call_api
    response_data = self.request(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 391, in request
    return self.rest_client.POST(url,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kubernetes/client/rest.py", line 276, in POST
    return self.request("POST", url,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kubernetes/client/rest.py", line 235, in request
    raise ApiException(http_resp=r)
kubernetes.client.exceptions.ApiException: (403)
Reason: Forbidden
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Audit-Id': '7871421d-254d-4d72-9a30-a7ff3306822b', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, private', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'X-Kubernetes-Pf-Flowschema-Uid': 'e5d21bfa-f8ff-4689-965a-2c8efc99569b', 'X-Kubernetes-Pf-Prioritylevel-Uid': 'f86dde2c-b36e-4c12-a44c-31e36a8ecf05', 'Date': 'Tue, 01 Aug 2023 00:32:51 GMT', 'Content-Length': '321'})
HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"jobs.batch is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:hm-prefect:prefect-worker\" cannot create resource \"jobs\" in API group \"batch\" in the namespace \"default\"","reason":"Forbidden","details":{"group":"batch","kind":"jobs"},"code":403}



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/prefect/workers/base.py", line 834, in _submit_run_and_capture_errors
    result = await self.run(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/prefect_kubernetes/worker.py", line 506, in run
    job = await run_sync_in_worker_thread(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/prefect/utilities/asyncutils.py", line 91, in run_sync_in_worker_thread
    return await anyio.to_thread.run_sync(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anyio/to_thread.py", line 33, in run_sync
    return await get_asynclib().run_sync_in_worker_thread(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 877, in run_sync_in_worker_thread
    return await future
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 807, in run
    result = context.run(func, *args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/prefect_kubernetes/worker.py", line 637, in _create_job
    message += ": " + exc.body["message"]
                      ~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'

Completed submission of flow run '065326e7-1d3e-455a-86fb-b15d553af5bd'
Reported flow run '065326e7-1d3e-455a-86fb-b15d553af5bd' as crashed: Flow run could not be submitted to infrastructure
```

Inside seems this line is the issue

> {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"jobs.batch is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:hm-prefect:prefect-worker" cannot create resource "jobs" in API group "batch" in the namespace "default"","reason":"Forbidden","details":{"group":"batch","kind":"jobs"},"code":403}

I am not sure why it tries to create job in the namespace `default` instead of `hm-prefect`. Any ideas? Thanks!

---

### UPDATE 1:

Based on @Stoat feedback. I did

```bash
➜ prefect init
? Would you like to initialize your deployment configuration with a recipe? [Use arrows to move; enter to select; n to select none]
┏━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃    ┃ Name         ┃ Description                                                                                   ┃
┡━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│    │ s3           │ Store code within an S3 bucket                                                                │
│ >  │ docker       │ Store code within a custom docker image alongside its runtime environment                     │
│    │ docker-s3    │ Store code within S3 and build a custom docker image for runtime                              │
│    │ docker-azure │ Store code within an Azure Blob Storage container and build a custom docker image for runtime │
│    │ azure        │ Store code within an Azure Blob Storage container                                             │
│    │ docker-gcs   │ Store code within GCS and build a custom docker image for runtime                             │
│    │ docker-git   │ Store code within a git repository and build a custom docker image for runtime                │
│    │ local        │ Store code on a local filesystem                                                              │
│    │ git          │ Store code within git repository                                                              │
│    │ gcs          │ Store code within a GCS bucket                                                                │
└────┴──────────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
    No, I'll use the default deployment configuration.
                         Required inputs for 'docker' recipe
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ Field Name ┃ Description                                                          ┃
┡━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│ image_name │ The image name, including repository, to give the built Docker image │
│ tag        │ The tag to give the built Docker image                               │
└────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
image_name: ghcr.io/hongbo-miao/hm-prefect-print-platform
tag: latest
---------------
Created project in /Users/hongbo-miao/Clouds/Git/hongbomiao.com/hm-prefect/workflows/print-platform with the following new files:
prefect.yaml
```

I removed `build` and `pubsh` section as my Docker image already built. Here is my updated **prefect.yaml**:
:

```yaml
name: print-platform
prefect-version: 2.11.1
pull:
- prefect.deployments.steps.set_working_directory:
    directory: /opt/prefect/print-platform
deployments:
- name: print-platform
  version: null
  tags: []
  description: null
  schedule: {}
  flow_name: null
  entrypoint: src/main.py:print_platform
  parameters: {}
  work_pool:
    name: hm-kubernetes-pool
    work_queue_name: null
    job_variables:
      image: ghcr.io/hongbo-miao/hm-prefect-print-platform
```

I hope avoid prompt, this is how I deploy:

```
➜ prefect --no-prompt deploy
╭────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│ Deployment 'print-platform/print-platform' successfully created with id 'e5bb4249-3a9f-4d62-bee2-fc9dce69fbd8'.                                            │
╰────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯

View Deployment in UI: https://prefect.hongbomiao.com/deployments/deployment/e5bb4249-3a9f-4d62-bee2-fc9dce69fbd8


To execute flow runs from this deployment, start a worker in a separate terminal that pulls work from the 'hm-kubernetes-pool' work pool:

        $ prefect worker start --pool 'hm-kubernetes-pool'

To schedule a run for this deployment, use the following command:

        $ prefect deployment run 'print-platform/print-platform'
```

Next I run

```bash
➜ prefect deployment run print-platform/print-platform
Creating flow run for deployment 'print-platform/print-platform'...
Created flow run 'charming-chimpanzee'.
└── UUID: 1f83d2ee-2584-424e-96ff-11e236ff7f1b
└── Parameters: {}
└── Scheduled start time: 2023-08-01 13:57:20 PDT (now)
└── URL: https://prefect.hongbomiao.com/flow-runs/flow-run/1f83d2ee-2584-424e-96ff-11e236ff7f1b
```

```bash
Worker 'KubernetesWorker 59a0fab6-b9c8-4668-b626-9a5cc0311250' submitting flow run '1f83d2ee-2584-424e-96ff-11e236ff7f1b'
Creating Kubernetes job...
Failed to submit flow run '1f83d2ee-2584-424e-96ff-11e236ff7f1b' to infrastructure.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 95, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
OSError: [Errno 113] No route to host

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 714, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 403, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1053, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 363, in connect
    self.sock = conn = self._new_conn()
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 186, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0xffffac3a3c10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 113] No route to host

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/prefect/workers/base.py", line 834, in _submit_run_and_capture_errors
    result = await self.run(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/prefect_kubernetes/worker.py", line 506, in run
    job = await run_sync_in_worker_thread(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/prefect/utilities/asyncutils.py", line 91, in run_sync_in_worker_thread
    return await anyio.to_thread.run_sync(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anyio/to_thread.py", line 33, in run_sync
    return await get_asynclib().run_sync_in_worker_thread(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 877, in run_sync_in_worker_thread
    return await future
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 807, in run
    result = context.run(func, *args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/prefect_kubernetes/worker.py", line 628, in _create_job
    job = batch_client.create_namespaced_job(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api/batch_v1_api.py", line 210, in create_namespaced_job
    return self.create_namespaced_job_with_http_info(namespace, body, **kwargs)  # noqa: E501
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api/batch_v1_api.py", line 309, in create_namespaced_job_with_http_info
    return self.api_client.call_api(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 348, in call_api
    return self.__call_api(resource_path, method,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 180, in __call_api
    response_data = self.request(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 391, in request
    return self.rest_client.POST(url,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kubernetes/client/rest.py", line 276, in POST
    return self.request("POST", url,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kubernetes/client/rest.py", line 169, in request
    r = self.pool_manager.request(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 78, in request
    return self.request_encode_body(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 170, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 376, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 826, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 826, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 826, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 798, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='10.43.0.1', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /apis/batch/v1/namespaces/default/jobs (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0xffffac3a3c10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 113] No route to host'))
Completed submission of flow run '1f83d2ee-2584-424e-96ff-11e236ff7f1b'
Reported flow run '1f83d2ee-2584-424e-96ff-11e236ff7f1b' as crashed: Flow run could not be submitted to infrastructure
```

This time the error is a little bit differnt. However, I am still lost.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is how you're creating your deployment - this is a common point of confusion so we are working on making this more clear in the docs.

TLDR: use `prefect deploy` not `prefect deployment build ...` when using workers.

The fundamental issue is that deployments created with `prefect deployment build` are assumed to be executed by an agent, and therefore will not correctly inherit the infra config from your work pool. Set `namespace` on your k8s work pool that you are pointing your new deployments at and create these new deployments via `prefect deploy`

e.g.

```
prefect deploy src/main.py:print_platform -p hm-kubernetes-pool
```

With `prefect deploy` (without any additional flags) the interactive wizard will find flow entrypoints in your project, you can select one, and the populate your deployment config based on your desired work pool, whether you want a schedule, etc. At the end of the wizard, you can save the config for your deployment for later use in CI or other non-interactive use

Using Prefect workers and work pools, there's extra information about each deployment you can pass to the server, for example a `pull` step that executes arbitrary processes while preparing for a flow run (if you want), most commonly `prefect.deployments.steps.git_clone`.

In order to define this info for each deployment, you can run `prefect init` in the root of your project dir and you'll see a `prefect.yaml` get created, where you can define deployments along with their [steps](https://docs.prefect.io/latest/concepts/deployments-ux/#deployment-actions).

You can edit your k8s work pool (which takes the place of the KubernetesJob infra block as far as defining job variables) and then override values (like `image` or `namespace`) on a per-deployment basis

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Stoat, I tried my best, and posted the new error I met n UPDATE 1. BTW, if there is any tutorial for worker, that would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: is this helpful @HongboMiao? https://docs.prefect.io/latest/guides/upgrade-guide-agents-to-workers/

Comment: Hi @Stoat, I mentioned in first comment. And posted the error based on your answer I met in the UPDATE 1 of the question.